# Replace Blank Lines and spaces java

Tags: java, lines

I have a java string like the one below which has multiple lines and blank spaces.  Need to remove all of them such that these are one line.

These are xml tags and the editor is not allowing to include less than symbol

```
<paymentAction>  

           Authorization

</paymentAction>
```

Should become

```
<paymentAction>AUTHORIZATION</paymentAction>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you really mean to make that last change? Now it doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1):

Calling `theString.replaceAll("\\s+","")` will replace all whitespace sequences with the empty string. Just be sure that the text between the tags doesn't contain spaces too, othewerise they'll get removed too.

Comment: Well, it sounds like the OP wants to keep one newline in between tags. Think we can adapt this to work with that?

Comment: @DennisMeng I don't know why you'd need to keep the newlines in between. However, this answer removes any whitespace, that's not going to work.

Comment: @JuanMendes Originally OP wanted each tag on one line.

Comment: @JuanMendes Then it could be possible to use something like `input.replaceAll(">\\s*([^<]*?)\\s*</", ">$1</"))`. The reluctant quantifier at `[^<]*?` ensures that trailing spaces will be matched by the following '\\s*' and ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to convert the XML you have to [Canonical Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML). Below is one way of doing it but it requires you to use that library. If you doesn't want to depend upon external libraries then another option for you is to use XSLT.

The [Canonicalizer](http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/c14n/Canonicalizer.html) class at Apache XML Security project:

NOTE: Dealing with non-xml aware API's (String.replaceAll()) is not generally recommended as you end up dealing with special/exception cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start. Probably not enough, but should be in the right direction.

```
xml.replaceAll(">\\s*", ">").replaceAll("\\s*<, "<");
```

However, I'm tempted to say there has to be a way to create a document from the XML and then serialize it in canonical form as Pangea suggested.